# Issues with cube stacking controller for Panda Robot using Behavior Trees and Task Space Control

Tags: python, robotic-arm, simulation, kinematics, inverse-kinematics

I have been working on a controller for a Panda (Franka Emika) robot (simulation, RobotDART and py_trees) and i can't figure out why the gripping mechanism doesn't work correctly. Initially the robot goes to the first cube quite fast but doesn't grab it. Then it freezes and most of the time wont go to the next target. My instructor's given information is very poor and i haven't been able to find anything on this matter. My constraints are as follows:

Controller must use Behavior Trees and a low-level task space controller

Simulation Environment details are time step 0.001s, using either fcl or bullet engine for collision detection.

Additional constraints:

1. Initial positions of robot and objects are predefined.
2. Cannot alter world and object descriptions.
3. Actuation via servo or torque motors.
4. Third-party libraries for computing controllers are not allowed, although optional libraries like pytrees are permitted.

As of now the robot's movements such as angle of approaching the first cube is not as it should. And the gripping mechanism fails to work. (I will provide a screenshot)

Here is my current script:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import py_trees
import RobotDART as rd
from transitions import Machine
import dartpy  # OSX breaks if this is imported before RobotDART


from utils import create_grid, create_problems, damped_pseudoinverse

dt = 0.001  # you are NOT allowed to change this
simulation_time = 40.0  # you are allowed to change this
total_steps = int(simulation_time / dt)

###
# DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING IN HERE
# Create robot
robot = rd.Franka(int(1. / dt))
init_position = [0., np.pi / 4., 0., -
                 np.pi / 4., 0., np.pi / 2., 0., 0.04, 0.04]

robot.set_positions(init_position)
robot.set_position_enforced(False)
robot_init = robot.clone_ghost()


max_force = 5.
robot.set_force_lower_limits(
    [-max_force, -max_force], ["panda_finger_joint1", "panda_finger_joint2"])
robot.set_force_upper_limits([max_force, max_force], [
                             "panda_finger_joint1", "panda_finger_joint2"])
####
robot.set_actuator_types("servo")  # you can use torque here

###
# DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING IN HERE
# Create boxes
box_positions = create_grid()

box_size = [0.04, 0.04, 0.04]

# Red Box
# Random cube position
red_box_pt = np.random.choice(len(box_positions))
box_pose = [0., 0., 0., box_positions[red_box_pt][0],
            box_positions[red_box_pt][1], box_size[2] / 2.0]
red_box = rd.Robot.create_box(box_size, box_pose, "free", 0.1, [
                              0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0], "red_box")


# Green Box
# Random cube position
green_box_pt = np.random.choice(len(box_positions))

while green_box_pt == red_box_pt:
    green_box_pt = np.random.choice(len(box_positions))
box_pose = [0., 0., 0., box_positions[green_box_pt][0],
            box_positions[green_box_pt][1], box_size[2] / 2.0]
green_box = rd.Robot.create_box(box_size, box_pose, "free", 0.1, [
                                0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 1.0], "green_box")

# Blue Box
# Random cube position
box_pt = np.random.choice(len(box_positions))

while box_pt == green_box_pt or box_pt == red_box_pt:
    box_pt = np.random.choice(len(box_positions))
box_pose = [0., 0., 0., box_positions[box_pt][0],
            box_positions[box_pt][1], box_size[2] / 2.0]
blue_box = rd.Robot.create_box(box_size, box_pose, "free", 0.1, [
                               0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0], "blue_box")
###
# Goal Box
# Random cube position
box_pt = np.random.choice(len(box_positions))

while box_pt == green_box_pt or box_pt == red_box_pt:
    box_pt = np.random.choice(len(box_positions))
box_pose = [0., 0., 0., box_positions[box_pt][0],
            box_positions[box_pt][1], box_size[2] / 2.0]
goal_box = rd.Robot.create_box(box_size, box_pose, "free", 0.1, [
    0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0], "goal_box")


# Random cube position
box_pt = np.random.choice(len(box_positions))

while box_pt == green_box_pt or box_pt == red_box_pt:
    box_pt = np.random.choice(len(box_positions))
box_pose = [0., 0., 0., box_positions[box_pt][0],
            box_positions[box_pt][1], box_size[2] / 2.0]
goal_box_1 = rd.Robot.create_box(box_size, box_pose, "free", 0.1, [
                                 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0], "goal_box")

###
# PROBLEM DEFINITION
# Choose problem
problems = create_problems()
problem_id = np.random.choice(len(problems))
problem = problems[problem_id]

print('We want to put the', problem[2], 'cube on top of the', problem[1],
      'and the', problem[1], 'cube on top of the', problem[0], 'cube.')
###

# find the order of the boxes the robot has to move to solve the problem

if problem[1] == 'red':
    first_box_name = red_box

elif problem[1] == 'green':
    first_box_name = green_box
else:
    first_box_name = blue_box

if problem[0] == 'red':
    second_box_name = red_box
elif problem[0] == 'green':
    second_box_name = green_box
else:
    second_box_name = blue_box

if problem[2] == 'red':
    third_box_name = red_box
elif problem[2] == 'green':
    third_box_name = green_box
else:
    third_box_name = blue_box

# Create Graphics
gconfig = rd.gui.Graphics.default_configuration()
gconfig.width = 1280  # you can change the graphics resolution
gconfig.height = 960  # you can change the graphics resolution
graphics = rd.gui.Graphics(gconfig)

# Create simulator object
simu = rd.RobotDARTSimu(dt)
simu.set_collision_detector("fcl")  # you can use bullet here
simu.set_control_freq(100)
simu.set_graphics(graphics)
graphics.look_at((0., 4.5, 2.5), (0., 0., 0.25))
simu.add_checkerboard_floor()
simu.add_robot(robot)
simu.add_robot(red_box)
simu.add_robot(blue_box)
simu.add_robot(green_box)
#########################################################
tmp = 0
flag = None

class PITask:
    def __init__(self, target, dt, Kp=1.2, Ki=0.8, flag=None):
        self._target = target
        self._dt = dt
        self._Kp = Kp
        self._Ki = Ki
        self._sum_error = np.zeros(6)
        self._flag = flag

    def set_target(self, target):
        self._target = target

    # function to compute error
    def error(self, tf):
        
        #compute error directly in world frame
        if self._flag == True:
            rot_error = rd.math.logMap(
                self._target.rotation() @ tf.rotation().T)
        else:
            #rot_error = rd.math.logMap(
            #   self._target.rotation() @ self._target.rotation())
            rot_error = rd.math.logMap(robot_init.body_pose("panda_ee").rotation() @ tf.rotation().T)

        lin_error = self._target.translation() - tf.translation()

        return np.r_[rot_error, lin_error]

    def update(self, current):
        error_in_world_frame = self.error(current)
        self._sum_error = self._sum_error + error_in_world_frame * self._dt
        return self._Kp * error_in_world_frame + self._Ki * self._sum_error

class ReachTarget(py_trees.behaviour.Behaviour):
    def __init__(self, robot, tf_desired, dt, goal_box, name, flag):
        super(ReachTarget, self).__init__(name)
        # robot
        self.robot = robot
        # end-effector name
        self.eef_link_name = "panda_ee"
        # set target tf
        self.tf_desired = dartpy.math.Isometry3()
        self.tf_desired.set_translation(tf_desired.translation())
        self.tf_desired.set_rotation(tf_desired.rotation())
        # dt
        self.dt = dt
        self.flag = flag
        self.name = name

        # goal box
        self.goal_box = goal_box

        self.logger.debug("%s.__init__()" % (self.__class__.__name__))

    def setup(self):
        self.logger.debug("%s.setup()->does nothing" %
                          (self.__class__.__name__))

    def initialise(self):
        self.logger.debug("%s.initialise()->init controller" %
                          (self.__class__.__name__))
        self.Kp = 1.2  # Kp could be an array of 6 values
        self.Ki = 0.8  # Ki could be an array of 6 values
        goal_box_pose = self.goal_box.body_pose(0)
        # if we want the robot to go to its starting position before moving the box
        if (self.flag == 1):
            # print(self.goal_box.body_pose(eef_link_name))
            goal_box_pose = self.goal_box.body_pose(eef_link_name)

            self.controller = PITask(
                goal_box_pose, self.dt, self.Kp, self.Ki, True)
        #if the robot completed all the tasks and now we want to end the simulation
        elif (self.flag == 2):
            simu.stop_sim()
            goal_box_pose = self.goal_box.body_pose(eef_link_name)

            self.controller = PITask(
                goal_box_pose, self.dt, self.Kp, self.Ki, True)
        #if we want the robot to go to the box position
        else:
            self.controller = PITask(
                goal_box_pose, self.dt, self.Kp, self.Ki, False)

    def update(self):
        new_status = py_trees.common.Status.RUNNING
        # control the robot
        tf = self.robot.body_pose(self.eef_link_name)
        vel = self.controller.update(tf)
        jac = self.robot.jacobian(self.eef_link_name)  # this is in world frame
        # np.linalg.pinv(jac) # get pseudo-inverse
        jac_pinv = damped_pseudoinverse(jac)
        cmd = jac_pinv @ vel
        #alpha = 10.
        #prev_cmd = alpha * (jac.T @ vel) # using jacobian transpose
        #new_cmd = 0.9 * prev_cmd + 0.1 * new_cmd  # Simple exponential smoothing

        self.robot.set_commands(cmd)
        # if error too small, report success
        err = np.linalg.norm(self.controller.error(tf))
        if err < 1e-3:

            init_time = time.time()
            simu.step()

            delay = 1
            #set a small delay to make sure the error is small for a while 
            #(so if the gripper moves the box even a little bit, it will not be considered as a success)
            while (time.time()-init_time < delay):
                simu.step()
                simu.step_world()
                err = np.linalg.norm(self.controller.error(tf))
                #if the error is small after the delay continue to close the gripper
                if err < 1e-3:
                    
                    gripper_velocity_command = 0.2

                    # Set the commands for both finger joints to close the gripper
                    self.robot.set_commands([gripper_velocity_command], [
                                            "panda_finger_joint1"])
                    simu.step_world()
                    init_time2 = time.time()
    enter code here
                    #set a small delay to make sure the gripper is closed
                    delay2 = 1.5
                    while (time.time()-init_time2 < delay2):
                        simu.step()
                        # simu.step_world()

                    new_status = py_trees.common.Status.SUCCESS
        if new_status == py_trees.common.Status.SUCCESS:
            self.feedback_message = "Reached target"
            self.logger.debug("%s.update()[%s->%s][%s]" % (
                self.__class__.__name__, self.status, new_status, self.feedback_message))
        else:
            self.feedback_message = "Error: {0}".format(err)
            self.logger.debug("%s.update()[%s][%s]" % (
                self.__class__.__name__, self.status, self.feedback_message))
        return new_status

    def terminate(self, new_status):
        self.logger.debug(
            "%s.terminate()[%s->%s]" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.status, new_status))


# get end-effector pose
eef_link_name = "panda_ee"
tf_desired = robot.body_pose(eef_link_name)
vec_desired = robot.body_pose_vec(eef_link_name)


# Behavior Tree

# Create tree root
root = py_trees.composites.Parallel(
    name="Root", policy=py_trees.common.ParallelPolicy.SuccessOnOne())
# Create sequence node (for sequential targets)
blackboard = py_trees.blackboard.Blackboard()
sequence = py_trees.composites.Sequence(name="Sequence", memory=blackboard)
# Target A
trA = ReachTarget(robot, tf_desired, dt, first_box_name, "Reach Target A", 0)
# add target to sequence node
sequence.add_child(trA)

# Target B
tf = dartpy.math.Isometry3()
tf.set_translation([tf_desired.translation()[0], tf_desired.translation()[
                   1], tf_desired.translation()[2]])
tf.set_rotation(tf_desired.rotation())
# we want to place the second box of the stack on top of the first box.
# so we need to move the gripper up by a little bit
goal_box_pose = [0., 0., 0., second_box_name.body_pose(0).translation()[0], second_box_name.body_pose(
    0).translation()[1], second_box_name.body_pose(0).translation()[2] + 0.08]
goal_box.set_positions(goal_box_pose)
trB = ReachTarget(robot, tf, dt, goal_box, "Reach Target B", 0)
# add target to sequence node
sequence.add_child(trB)


# Target Initial
tf = dartpy.math.Isometry3()
tf.set_translation([tf_desired.translation()[0],
                   tf_desired.translation()[1], tf_desired.translation()[2]])
tf.set_rotation(tf_desired.rotation())
# we go to the initial position of the robot to avoid collisions with the box
trIn = ReachTarget(robot, tf, dt, robot_init, "Reach Target Initial", 1)
# add target to sequence node
sequence.add_child(trIn)

# Target C
tf = dartpy.math.Isometry3()
tf.set_translation([tf_desired.translation()[0],
                   tf_desired.translation()[1], tf_desired.translation()[2]])
tf.set_rotation(tf_desired.rotation())
# we go to pickup the third box of the stack
trC = ReachTarget(robot, tf, dt, third_box_name, "Reach Target C", 0)
# add target to sequence node
sequence.add_child(trC)


# Target D
tf = dartpy.math.Isometry3()
tf.set_translation([tf_desired.translation()[0],
                   tf_desired.translation()[1], tf_desired.translation()[2]])
tf.set_rotation(tf_desired.rotation())
goal_box_pose_1 = [0., 0., 0., second_box_name.body_pose(0).translation()[0], second_box_name.body_pose(
    0).translation()[1], second_box_name.body_pose(0).translation()[2] + 0.16]
goal_box_1.set_positions(goal_box_pose_1)
# we want to place the third box of the stack on top of the second box.
# so we need to move the gripper up by a little bit of the second box
trD = ReachTarget(robot, tf, dt, goal_box_1, "Reach Target D", 0)
# add target to sequence node
sequence.add_child(trD)

# Target End
tf = dartpy.math.Isometry3()
tf.set_translation([tf_desired.translation()[0],
                   tf_desired.translation()[1], tf_desired.translation()[2]])
tf.set_rotation(tf_desired.rotation())
trEnd = ReachTarget(robot, tf, dt, robot_init, "Reach Target End", 2)
# add target to sequence node
sequence.add_child(trEnd)


# Add sequence to tree
root.add_child(sequence)

# Render tree structure
# py_trees.display.render_dot_tree(root)

# tick once[![enter image description here][1]][1]
root.tick_once()
cnt = 0

for step in range(total_steps):
    if (simu.schedule(simu.control_freq())):

        root.tick_once()
        current_positions = robot.positions(["panda_finger_joint1", "panda_finger_joint2"])
        print(f"Current Gripper Positions: {current_positions}")
    if (simu.step_world()):
        break
```